# Can we overwrite 'expect' method of testcafe's TestController

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am looking for a way to overwrite expect method for TestController. My idea is existing tests whoever used t.expect method, I want to perform additional steps in those cases.
I came up with below sample code but testcafe runtime fails with below error
`TypeError: Cannot read property '_expect$' of undefined`

sample code attempting to override:

```
import { Selector } from "testcafe";

fixture`Getting Started`.page`http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/example`;

test("My first test", async (t) => {
  t = modify(t);
  await t.typeText("#developer-name", "John Smith").click("#submit-button");

  // Use the assertion to check if the actual header text is equal to the expected one
  await t
    .expect(Selector("#article-header").innerText)
    .eql("Thank you, John Smith!");
});

function modify(t) {
  let prevExpect = t.expect;
  t.expect = (param) => {
    console.log("modified expecte has been used");
    return prevExpect(param);
  };
  return t;
}
```

Also, when using  `t.click(Selector(...).expect(...)`, It doesn't use my overwritten expect. How to make it work in the call chain as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, it's possible to overwrite the `expect` method, but please note that this approach may lead to incorrect work and unexpected errors.
You need to modify your `modify` function as follows:

```
function modify (t) {
    let prevExpect = t.expect;

    t.expect       = (param) => {
        console.log("modified expect has been used");

        return prevExpect.call(t, param);
    };
    return t;
}
```

As for the `t.click(Selector(...).expect(...)` issue, you call the `expect` method of Selector, but Selector does not have the `expect` method.
You need to add `)` after Selector:

`await t.click(Selector(...)).expect(...)`

Comment: Thanks @AlexKamaev. My use case  of  additional check is to use [axe-testcafe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axe-testcafe) to collect accessibility issues without modifying existing test cases.